# How would you address one dimensional memory using two dimensions?

Tags: c++, memory, matrix

How would you address one dimensional memory using two dimensions? (Such as getting the value `Matrix::ValueAt(row, col)` where `Matrix` stores the values as a one dimensional array (`float m[16]` for a 4x4 matrix).

```
class Matrix4x4
{
    private float m[16];

    float getValueAt(int row, int col)
    {
        // I want this function
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `m[row * 4 + col]`, or the other way around.

Comment: and what if it is an mxn matrix?

Comment: @AmaldeepPrakash `row * m + col`. That question tells me you didn't understand the solution.

Comment: i was just confirming..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let the compiler figure it out:

```
class Matrix4x4
{
private:
    union
    {
        float m[16];
        float m2[4][4];
    };
public:
    float getValueAt(int row, int col)    
    {
        return m2[row][col];
    }

    float getValueAtLinear(int i)    
    {
        return m[i];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general:

Matrix(i,j) = m[i * columns + j]